# When would standard topology "equal" to lower limit topology?

Tags: general-topology

I know that the lower limit topology is strictly finer than the standard topology. Therefore, for any set $A$, $T_{std}|_A\subset T_{ll}|_A$. But is there any condition that $T_{std}|_A= T_{ll}|_A$, I feel like countability of $A$ would do the job, but I cannot prove it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Countability of $A$ is necessary but not sufficient: $\Bbb Q$ is countable, but $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)$ is open in the lower limit topology but not not in the standard topology.

You need to make sure that for each $a\in A$, $[a,\to)\cap A$ is a relatively open subset of $A$ in the usual topology. This means that for each $a\in A$ there must be an $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $(x,\to)\cap A=[a,\to)\cap A$, which amounts to saying that $x<a$ and $(x,a)\cap A=\varnothing$. In other words, no point of $A$ can be a limit from the left of other points of $A$.

Comment: Nice answer @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @ChrisCuster: Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you give a hint on how to prove Countability is necessary?@BrianM.Scott

Comment: @xyz: You’re welcome. It follows from the fact that for each $a\in A$ there must be an $x_a\in\Bbb R$ such that $x_a<a$ and $(x_a,a)\cap A=\varnothing$. The intervals $(x_a,a)$ are pairwise disjoint (why?); each must contain a rational, no two can contain the same rational, and there are only countably many rationals, so … ?