# If f: $\mathbb{R}_{l} \rightarrow S_{\Omega}$ is continuous, then f is not injective.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, order-topology, sorgenfrey-line

**If f: $\mathbb{R}_{l} \rightarrow S_{\Omega}$ is continuous, then f is not injective.**

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days, but I haven't been able to see how can I do it. First, $\mathbb{R}_{l}$ refers to $\mathbb{R}$ with the lower limit topology (generated by intervals of the form $[a,b)$ ) and $S_{\Omega}$ refers to the uncountable well-ordered set with the order topology (generated by (a,b) and rays). Until now, I've tried to use the fact that both of those topologic spaces are Hausdorff and suppose that f is injective to get a contradiction, but I don't see where can I get it.

Comment: There are lots of Hausdorff spaces embedding into other Hausdorff spaces so using Hausdorffness will never bring you anything. Think of other distinguishing topological properties between these spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $y=\min S_\Omega$; then $\{y\}$ is open in $S_\Omega$, so if $f:\Bbb R_\ell\to S_\Omega$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is open in $\Bbb R_\ell$. Does $\Bbb R_\ell$ have any isolated points?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f: \Bbb R_l \to S_\Omega$ be an injective continuous function. We strive for a contradiction:

Let $f[\Bbb R_l]$ be the image in $S_\Omega$, which is a non-empty set so $m = \min f[\Bbb R_l]$ exists, so there is a unique (by injectivity of $f$) $x_0 \in \Bbb R_l$ with $f(x_0)=m$. In the order topology on $S_\Omega$, the set $O= \{x\mid x < m+1\}$ is open so that $f^{-1}[O] = \{x_0\}$ (identity clear from minimality of $m$ and uncity of $x_0$) is open in $\Bbb R_l$, contradicting that all non-empty open subsets of $\Bbb R_l$ are uncountable (they contain a set of the form $[a,b), a < b$).

Comment: Note that we need very little of $\Bbb R_l$: the same proof essentially shows that there cannot be an injective continuous map from any space without isolated points into any ordinal space in the order topology. The well-orderedness of the latter is quite restrictive.

Comment: Or slightly more general: no injective continuous map exists from a crowded space into a scattered space.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is injective, then you  have an imbedding of $[a,b]$ onto  $f([a,b])$.  But it is easy to see that an uncountable set with the order topology cannot have the same topology as the lower limit topology.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4011876/403337).